# How to use context leaderboard in facebook instant game sdk

Tags: typescript, facebook-instant-games, cocoscreator

I am using Cocos Creator with TypeScript to code a Facebook Instant Game. My game is a single-player game, and I want to save the scores of all players to create a leaderboard and then retrieve the top 10 players. However, I have read in the Facebook documentation that global leaderboards are no longer supported.

I have tried using the context leaderboard, but it still isn't effective. Is there any way to address my issue?